# Delete cache in edge browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, cachestorage

I was trying to delete caches using this code

```
async function test () {
    cacheKeys = await caches.keys();
    cacheKeys.map(async cacheKey => {
        caches.delete(cacheKey);
        await deleteIndexedDBDatabase(cacheKey);
    });
}
```

The code works fine in chrome but not in edge. It is not even throwing an error
Has anyone resolved similar issue

Comment: @JohnPavek "It is not even throwing an error"

Answer (score 0):

The function works fine . There seems to be an issue with latest edge dev tools . They sometimes show data even after deletion .